# Bypassing KeyError: 'type' when running a ArcGIS Online Python Notebook meant to overwrite organizational CSV

Tags: arcgis-online, csv, arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

I have a scheduled organizational script that is only meant to be run during the summer and is left dormant for the winter as the data it scrapes is not maintained at that time. The reason I am mentioning that is that it was working just as intended when it was stopped in September 2022, but is now running into an error when run.

The script is meant to scrape a csv file and overwriting a specific csv item on ArcGIS Online whenever it runs. This allows for other items to reference the specific csv without the source changing. Here is the code I currently have for the export process:

```
SERVICE_NAME = "cwfis_active_v2"
SERVICE_TITLE = "CWFIS - Active Fires v2"
CSV_FILE="/arcgis/home/{0}.csv".format(SERVICE_NAME)

c.to_csv(CSV_FILE, index=False)
csv_item = None
csv_items = gis.content.search(query="{0}.csv".format(SERVICE_NAME))
if len(csv_items) > 0:
    print("Using existing item!")
    csv_item = csv_items[0]
    csv_item.update(data=CSV_FILE)
else:
    print("Creating new item!")
    item_properties = {
        "title": SERVICE_TITLE,
        "name": SERVICE_NAME,
        "type": "CSV",
        "locationType":"none"
    }
    csv_item = gis.content.add(
        item_properties=item_properties,
        data=CSV_FILE
    )
source_info = gis.content.analyze(item=csv_item)
source_info["name"] = SERVICE_NAME
source_info["title"] = SERVICE_TITLE
csv_layer_item = csv_item.publish(
    publish_parameters=source_info,
    overwrite=True
)
display(csv_layer_item)
```

What used to run just as expected now produces this error, highlighting the entire csv.item_publish() function:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [68], in <cell line: 27>()
     25 source_info["name"] = SERVICE_NAME
     26 source_info["title"] = SERVICE_TITLE
---> 27 csv_layer_item = csv_item.publish(
     28     publish_parameters=source_info,
     29     overwrite=True
     30 )
     31 display(csv_layer_item)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/__init__.py:13918, in Item.publish(self, publish_parameters, address_fields, output_type, overwrite, file_type, build_initial_cache, item_id, geocode_service)
  13912 elif (
  13913     "success" in ret[0]
  13914     and ret[0]["success"] == False
  13915     and ret[0].get("error", None)
  13916 ):
  13917     raise Exception(ret[0].get("error"))
> 13918 elif not buildInitialCache and ret[0]["type"].lower() == "image service":
  13919     return Item(self._gis, ret[0]["serviceItemId"])
  13920 else:

KeyError: 'type'
```

I have found some mentions of a similar issue online, but I'm perplexed as to how the script no longer works without having changed.

Comment: also having this problem